# Best etymological calque of the word Schadenfreude

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, germanic-languages

This question is purely theoretical (i.e. I don't foresee actually trying to use the word), but using arguments based on etymology, as well as euphony and (least importantly) comprehensibility, what is the most etymologically faithful English equivalent for the German ***Schadenfreude***?

Other Germanic languages use etymologically translated calques: ***skadefryd*** (Danish & Norwegian), ***schadevreugde*** (Dutch). English has a cognate word for German ***Schaden***, Dutch ***schade***, Danish & Norwegian ***skade***, Swedish ***skada*** (all of which mean *damage/injury*) in the form of ***scathe*** (which also means *damage/injury*) – all descended from Proto-Germanic ***​*skaþô*** (*damage/injury*) – so it is reasonable to propose that the first part of the theoretical English word should be *scath-*, *scathe-* or *skaith-*.

The difficulty lies with the second part – English does have a word ***frith*** (*peace/sanctuary*) that is a distant cousin of German ***Freude***, Dutch ***vreugde***, Danish & Norwegian ***fryd*** (all of which mean *joy*); but it is a closer relation to German ***Frieden***, Dutch ***vrede***, Danish & Norwegian ***fred*** (all of which mean *peace*), these words and ***frith*** all being descended from Proto-Germanic ***⁠*friþuz*** (*peace*). One could opt for -*frith* : ***scathefrith*** is viable.

Or one could take the Swedish option (*skadeglädje*) and replace the last part with a different word for joy (***glädje*** = *gladness*) : ***scathgladness*** or ***skaithgladness*** are options.

The question(s) are which of these three options (***scathefrith***, ***scathgladness*** or ***skaithgladness***) is the best, and is there a better option? Can someone pull a (perhaps obscure, perhaps archaic or even Old) English word out the bag that is a closer relation to ***Freude/vreugde/fryd***? Or perhaps a word with a slightly different etymology that is better for other reasons?

P.S.
Apologies if such questions are not appropriate on English SE, but it is a technical question looking for a technical answer, however theoretical it may be.

Comment: Not exactly a technical answer but I always used to mentally translate it to sad-happiness. It doesn't fully convey the idea but if you understand the concept it kinda makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for this. *Frith* is a fine word (and I don’t mean the Forth one :), but it is known only to a few these days. Your question makes me wonder whether Frodo, who hardly escaped unscathed, experienced Schadenfreude when Gollum fell into the fire.  Or maybe scathenfrodo. :)  Most people today have forgotten [Fróði/Froda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fróði), the old king, and think that *Frodo* came out of nowhere — but he didn’t.  Frodo is just the modernized version of Froda.

Comment: **Skaithgloat** or **scathegloat**? ***Scathegloating*** has a nice rhythmic and semantic symmetry with ***scapegoating***.

Comment: In *scathefrisson*, *[frisson](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=frisson)* like *Freude* begins with *fr*, but apparently isn't etymologically related

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schadenfreude) takes up this question in some detail.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schadenfreude#English_equivalents

Comment: @Dan’s _scathegloat_ is obviously less etymologically sound, being based on only one cognate and one non-cognate; but it is a brilliant creation nonetheless. It is euphonic, sounds like a proper endemic word, and is easy to grasp and remember. I'm going to start using _scathegloat_ instead of _Schadenfreude_ in English.

Comment: If I was opting for a less etymological option, I'd be tempted to go for "contrasmug"/"contrasmugness" – but "scathegloat" is still a great option.

Comment: Incidentally, is _scathe_ not basically disqualified by definition, being just as much of a loan word as _Schadenfreude_ (albeit a much earlier one)?

Comment: I have never heard of an etymologically faithful equivalent in translation. This is a game, but not translation.

Comment: Don't you think schadenfreude remains a loan word for two reasons? Secondly, none-too many English-speaking people understand it in the second place but even before that the cognoscenti concur, there isn't even a good etymological calque, let alone one worthy of being acknowledged "best".

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin  I guess we share the same weltanschauung. An example of an etymological "calque" is tennis for the French: tenez, here you go.

Comment: This is way out of my depth, but no-one has mentioned *blithe* yet. It's Germanic in origin, has plenty of cognates, and means joyous, although kindness is in the mix and might prejudice it a bit in this instance.  And *scatheblithe* has a fun symmetry.

Comment: @Janus I am not sure it's meaningful to characterize an English word from Old Norse as a 'mere loanword'.

Comment: @Spencer I didn’t say ‘mere’ (since I don’t believe there’s anything ‘mere’ about loan words); I only said that it is a loan word, which it is. It’s not an inherited English word. The only difference between _scathe_ and _Schade(nfreude)_ is one of time: the former was borrowed around 1200, the latter not until around 1900. But they’re both loan words, no less so than the many French loan words that entered English around the same time as _scathe_ was borrowed.

Answer (score 6):

### Background

English 'schadenfreude', a noun attested from 1867 in [*OED*](http://oed.com/), derives directly from German *schadenfreude*, a noun-noun compound. *Schade* meant "damage, harm, injury", viz.

> [image: 'schaden' image from Kluge, tr. Davis, 1891]
>
> [*An etymological dictionary of the German language*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015005765295;view=1up;seq=321;size=175). By Friedrich Kluge, translated by John Francis Davis. The date of the (translated) author's preface indicates the gloss and etymological details stemmed from lexical work completed no later than 1888 and most likely completed before 1883.

*Freude* meant "joy, pleasure, delight", viz.

> [image: 'freude' image from Kluge etc.]
>
> [op. cit.](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015005765295;view=1up;seq=120;size=175)

An Englished meaning of the *schadenfreude* compound is given by [William Dwight Whitney in the 1877 edition of *A compendious German and English dictionary*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=nyp.33433084115322;view=1up;seq=364;size=175) as "pleasure at the misfortune of others, malignant joy", viz.

> [image: 'schadenfreude' image from Whitney 1877]

The English meaning given by Whitney in 1877 for the German compound *schadenfreude* is the meaning retained by the adopted English compound 'schadenfreude' to this day.

### *Schaden*

This investigator accepts the original poster's suggestion that 'scathe' serves well for the first part of the desired "best etymological calque" compound, especially because [*OED*](http://oed.com/)'s sense 2a (not shown as obsolete in an entry not "fully updated" since 1910) for "**scathe**, *n.*" is

> Hurt, harm, damage.

Although 'scathe' in this sense is in my estimation obsolescent today (except as found in the participial adjective 'scathing'), the poster of the question indicated that contemporary obsolescence was not at issue for a desirable answer.

### *Freude*

Kluge, in particular, suggested a number of cognates that might be investigated while attempting to find what the original poster of the question announced in comments they were looking for, the investigation target also implicit in the question:

> an obscure, obsolete or even Old English word that was derived from the same root as Freude.

The cognates suggested by Kluge can be supplemented from [*Deutsches Wörterbuch von Jacob Grimm und Wilhelm Grimm*](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GF08751#XGF08751) to include "freuen, MidHG", "*vröuwen*, OHG", "*frouwen*", and "*ahd.* frawida, frewida, frowida, *mhd.* vreude, vröude, *nhd. bei*".

An exhaustive search of the *OED* for "obscure, obsolete or even Old English" words derived from any of the cognates suggested by Kluge and the Grimms failed to bear fruit.

Bearing in mind, however, that the original question stipulated "comprehensibility" as of lesser importance than etymology and euphony, and also bearing in mind that there was no indication in the question that complete agreement with contemporary English usage should be desirable, Kluge's suggestion to "see *froh*" seemed worthwhile. Also, Whitney gave *schadenfroh* as the adjectival counterpart of *schadenfreude*, with the meaning "pleased at the misfortune of others, malignant, mischievous".

*Froh* is glossed by Kluge as "glad, joyous, happy" in English:

> [image: *froh*, image from Kluge 1891] 
>   [image: *froh* image continued]
>
> Kluge, 1891.

Leaping from [*freude* to its reconstructed (that is, unattested) Proto-Indo-European root, **prew-*, meaning "to jump, hop"](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Freude#Etymology), and from there to [a posited Proto-Germanic **frawaz*](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/frawaz), the English word 'frolic' is suggested as a descendant, via Dutch, Middle Dutch and Old Dutch.

*OED* gave the noun 'frolic' as deriving from either the verb or the adjective; the etymology of the adjective 'frolic' associates the Middle Dutch form *vrô* with the modern German *froh*.

> Dutch *vrolijk* (in Kilian *vrolick*), = Old Saxon *frôlîc* (whence *frôlîco* adverb), Old High German *frôlîch* (Middle High German *vrôlich*, *vrœlic*, modern German *fröhlich*); < Middle Dutch *vrô* = Old High German *frô* (Middle High German *vrô*, modern German ***froh***) glad, joyous.
>
> (Bold emphasis mine.)

Of the etymology of the verb 'frolic', *OED* remarks that the second element, *-licken* (Flemish) or *-lochen* is "of obscure origin".

### New Compound

The foregoing suggests that the neologistic compound **scathe-frolic** serves to answer the question of what, "using arguments based on etymology, as well as euphony and (least importantly) comprehensibility", is the "most etymologically faithful English equivalent for the German *Schadenfreude*?"

'Euphony', of course, may be considered a matter of personal taste or a matter to be settled by consensus; scathe-frolic sounds pleasant enough to my ear, and seems easy to pronounce. If, as I suspect, the original question meant by 'euphony' something more like *sound-similarity* than "pleasing and easy to pronounce", the phonic similarity of the first syllable of '-frolic' and the entirety of 'freude', while somewhat slantwise (at least in my pronunciations), is self-evident.

'Comprehensibility', the least important of the stipulations, is in my opinion largely determined by familiarity with the compound used with the particular meaning of "pleasure at the misfortunes of others, malignant joy". However, it might be argued that, absent knowledge of the intended meaning, 'scathe-frolic' would lend itself to, among other interpretations, interpretation as a synonym of 'algolagnia', active or passive or both, where 'algolagnia' is defined as

> The practice of deriving pleasure, *esp.* sexual pleasure, from pain inflicted on oneself or others; the urge or tendency to derive pleasure in this way. Cf. SADOMASOCHISM *n*.
>     <sub>Often divided into *active* and *passive* algolagnia, corresponding to sadism and masochism respectively.</sub>
>
> *OED*

Other possible interpretations, again absent knowledge of the intended meaning of "pleasure at the misfortunes of others, malignant joy", might involve association with, for example, unlucky outcomes for extreme sports. I suggest, though, that once the intended meaning has been associated with the term, it will come to seem natural — at least as if not more natural than that meaning associated with 'schadenfreude'.

Comment: I can't believe some poor soul actually translated Kluge into English. There's a .pdf of the German original bouncing around the internet.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive and erudite answer. This is just the kind of content and voice I was hoping to attract.  I'm a little sad that no obscure cognate to freude could be found, but I'm pleased with the overall argument. +500, with my thanks and congratulations.

Comment: @DanBron, my pleasure, really. Much of my pleasure is the hunt; whether the beast is caught counts very little. In this case, if the PIE and Proto-Germanic comparative evidence has been accurately interpreted (by those in a better position to do so than I am), 'frolic' is cognate with *freude*, having descended from **prew-* with differences ascribable to separate phonetic development. Certainly the sense of "to jump, hop" hasn't been lost from 'frolic', or even from *freude* if my notion of "joy, pleasure, delight" is shared.

Answer (score 4):

*Scathe* is indeed cognate to German *Schaden*, and there is a scarcely known nominal form as well. The general sense of "harm, damage," however, is only available in *unscathed*, as the non-metaphorical *scathe* carries a strong association with fire. If one returns to the Old English *[sceaþian](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/scea%C3%BEian#/search)*, and imagine its meaning never having been narrowed — and that there was never such a thing as the Great Vowel Shift — a new derivative of this verb might be more suitable for the first part of the compound.

The second element is more problematic, mostly because *-frith* or *-frid* makes any compound with an equally Germanic first element sound like a minor character in a Wagnerian opera — Siegfried's trusted groomsman, Skaithfrid — or an ancient king, Skathefrith the Lame. Using *-gloat* would be imprecise, because it may describe the results, but not the sentiment of Schadenfreude.

The Swedish solution, then, might recommend itself: *sceathgladness* with its accompanying adjective *sceathglad*. The German *Freude*, however, [ultimately derives from a PIE root meaning "to jump,"](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Freude#Etymology) and English speakers don't jump for gladness, but *joy*, which has the decided advantage of being the best translation of *Freude*: think Beethoven.

*[Joy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/joy?s=t)*, however, is not Germanic and does not even number among the Germanic words borrowed into French, but comes from Latin *gaudium*. I still would prefer *joy*, if only for the word *sceathjoyous*, which I would insist on pronouncing with the stress on the second syllable.

So one is left with *sceathjoy*, the Swedish-ish *sceathgladness*, or your bit part in the Ring Cycle.

---

It seems to me that on the way across the Atlantic, a key element of *Schadenfreude* has been minimized, and that is that it's most often experienced as a result of what one could call "banana peel justice." If one sees an elderly woman slip on the ice, only the most callous would experience *Schadenfreude*, but if it's, say, a self-important politician whose views one doesn't share, one jumps for *Schadenfreude*:

> [Schadenfreude](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schadenfreude) scheint eine dominante Rolle beim Erhalt von Gerechtigkeit und der Bestrafung von Normverstößen in menschlichen Gesellschaften zu spielen.
>
> In human societies, *Schadenfreude* appears to play a dominant role in maintaining justice and punishing transgressions against social norms.

Recovering this nuance, I think, would be of greater value than recovering Old English roots.

Comment: Wow! Nice work! We have a contender here!

Comment: Try *glee* for *joy*:  From Old English *glíw, gléo*; meaning “Mirth, joy, rejoicing; in modern use, a lively feeling of delight caused by special circumstances and finding expression in appropriate gestures and looks.”

Comment: Wouldn't that just sound like a bizarre -ly adverb?

Comment: *Scatheglee* you mean? Hm.

Comment: Scathgly the serpent slithered into the night.

Comment: I like **scathejoy**

Answer (score 3):

Although not an A-S scholar, I've always thought Scathfrith would be the best from-A-S equivalent of Schadenfreude.  (I had originally thought "shadefrith" would be better, but etymologically it isn't as good as scathfrith or scathefrith.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what OP means by "best etymological calque" here. Obviously there's no succinct equivalent "word-by-word translation" equivalent - that's why we (and several other languages) adopted the foreign term in the first place.

Those who understand the two German words could perhaps "fill in the blanks" around the explicitly-stated ***harm/joy*** elements as...

> *[another's] **misfortune** [causing] **enjoyment** [for you]*

I'm not 100% certain exactly what sense is intended by [the following](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22and%20let%20us%20agree%20for%20once%20that%20truth%20is%20a%20greater%20sin%20than%20falsehood%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22pain%20vampire%22&tbm=bks), but it seems pretty close...

> *"I thought she was a **pain vampire**"*

Comment: By “best etymological calque”, I believe he means a direct, literal translation from the German word that uses English cognates of the German _Schade_ and _Freude_, but which are also understandable to normal English speakers. _Scathefrith_ is an excellent etymological calque, but it suffers from the disadvantage that nobody says _frith_ (or knows what it means) anymore.

Comment: @Janus: oic. I thought OP was just after some juxtaposition of two *English* words that might convey something of the same relationship and total meaning as the two German words. I'm now having trouble understanding how the question is relevant to ELU, if answering it requires one to know German (or archaic German "borrowings" that have long fallen into disuse).

Comment: @FumbleFingers : OP was looking ideally for a etymologically defendended cognate-based calque of Schadenfreude – my main issue with "scathefrith" was that "frith" was descended from a Proto-Germanic word that though a cousin of an acestor of Freude was actually a direct ancestor of Frieden and was wondering if there was an obscure, obsolete or even Old English word that was derived from the same root as Freude. And whilst ELU's mission statement doesn't say anything about German, it does mention etymology, so I reckoned that questions about Proto-Germanic derived terms were kosher.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm with you here. As a translator myself, I have never heard of a "best etymological calque". I would love to see another example....from any language into English.  Word-for-word equivalents are known as literal translations. Generally speaking, either one uses a good approximation of the meaning or the word itself. After all, one does see the word in English texts so I think this is basically a fool's errand.

Answer (score 2):

> [Schadenfreude (n.)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/schadenfreude) "malicious joy in the misfortunes of others," 1922, German Schadenfreude, literally "damage-joy," from schaden "damage, harm, injury" (see scathe) + freude, from Old High German frewida "joy," from fro "happy," literally "hopping for joy," from Proto-Germanic *frawa- (see [frolic](https://www.etymonline.com/word/frolic?ref=etymonline_crossreference)).

After consulting my Webster's Dictionary, I propose that the most aptly expressed English calque of the German noun, **schadenfreude**, might be the compound noun, **scatfrolic** (or **scat-frolic**):

[image: portrait of Noah Webster, L.L.D.] [image: title page of Webster's Unabridged Dictionary, c.1959]

[image: scat-frolic]

...inasmuch as **scat (n.)** may be British dialect for: **a blow**, [**spat**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/spat), or **hurt**; wherein *spat* may be defined: *smack or slap, attested from 1823*. [*Frolic*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXcmPS_bIBA) is likewise used in its noun sense of meaning [*happy-dance*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPoOQieqM50).

**Scatfrolic** or **scat-frolic** perfectly captures the emotionally and intellectually stunted attitude of receiving pleasure from the misery of others.

Another English version that might work, is the compound noun **scatfree** or **scat-free**, replacing *frolic* with *free*, in the adjective sense of meaning [beloved or loving](https://www.etymonline.com/word/free), from the Old Norse, *Frigg*.

Both examples sound appropriate for the meaning, while suggesting double-entendres for added interest.

Answer (score 2):

### Smirkmishap

A 21st century candidate, whose meaning can be easily guessed. Like schadenfreude, it is a compound noun composed of "[smirk](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/smirk)" (both a noun and verb) and "[mishap](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/mishap)"

> **mishap**
>   Middle English: from mis- + hap.
>
> **smirk**
>   Old English *sme(a)rcian*, from a base shared by smile.

Merriam-Webster defines "smirk" as

> *verb*
>   : to smile in an unpleasant way because you are pleased with yourself, **[glad about someone else's trouble](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smirk)**, etc.

### What does the OP intend by calque?

The word calque is derived from the French *calque*, and it means to translate literally word-for-word a foreign word or expression. For example,
["Groundhog" may be a calque from Dutch "aertoercken."](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/calque)

An additional example would be the English term ***wisdom tooth*** and the Italian ***dente del giudizio***,  both are the calque of the Latin ***dēns sapientiae***. Using the strict criteria set by the OP and its bounty benefactor, the  "best etymological calque" of *sapientia* would not be *wisdom*, derived from Old High German *wistuom*, but instead *[sapience](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sapience#English)*. Moreover, the Italian word *giudizio* (judgement) is not a cognate of *sapentia* but of Latin *iudicium*.

There is no rule, anywhere, that a calque must be formed by cognates. It's simply untrue, and the OP's quest is senseless and flawed. A much more realistic approach, from a linguistic point of view, would be to translate the loanword using common English words whose meaning are naturally intuitive. Therefore, **to smirk at someone's mishap**, translates the meaning of *schadenfreude*, rather neatly. It just so happens that "smirk" has Old English origins and is possibly derived from Proto-Germanic  *smarōną* while the Germanic-sounding *mishap* is a compound word that incorporates the prefix *mis-* with the virtually obsolete and archaic **[hap](https://www.etymonline.com/word/hap?ref=etymonline_crossreference)**, meaning "luck", "fortune". *Hap* dates back to Proto-Germanic  *hap- (source of Old English *gehæp* "convenient, fit"), it is no longer used in the English language but its derivatives, *hapless* and *mishap*, have survived to the present-day.